# Resolved by field in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api, jira-rest-api

I need to search records in JIRA by using jira key. I am able to search issues but I have to do one more task that is to find out resolved by and resolved date. I had did lots of goggling but did not find content which satisfied me.

I really appreciate to help me to solve out this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to solve out this problem by traversing history data. I used json call to pick history data on basis of jira key then I converted that history data into typed history collection and started looking for Resolved token. When I got Resolved token in history then I picked the assigned name. By this way I am able to solve out this problem.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a calculated field using Script Runner to extract the information from the Issue History tab. Not sure how good the search is using that approach. Alternatively you can use the REST API and a script to scan issues, but that's probably too slow.

Comment: I had extract history of issue using JSON but I would like to know is there are any direct way which give me resolved by and resolved date by supplying JIRA key. Like any third part dll or any web service provided by JIRA.